# Is a permutation test with max statistics appropriate to account for multiple comparisons when searching for correlations between two questionnaires?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, matlab, permutation-test, spearman-rho

I'm trying to understand if the max statistic method for permutation test is appropriate to use and how i should apply it in my situation:

I have a sample of 38 individuals who performed a task and we administered two questionnaires to them: the nasa-tlx, which has 6 subdomains, and a questionnaire we wrote on usability of the tool used, made of 5 Likert-scale items, and an open ended question.

We wanted to see if there were significant correlations (calculated with Spearman's rho) between each subdomain of the nasa-tlx (mental demand, performance, effort, ecc) and each question of our questionnaire (minus the open ended question).

So we have a 6x5 matrix of possible correlations between the two outcomes.

Am i correct that i should correct for multiple comparisons in this case?
Each participants has 1 score for each subdomain and each item of the questionnaire.

I don't think Bonferroni correction is appropriate in this case, because some of the variables probably correlate with each other (like effort, performance, and physical demand, for example).

So i thought that i could use a permutation test with max statistics, which should correct for multiple comparisons, but i've never tried it before so i'm a little unsure on how to apply it.
I found this [matlab](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34920-mult_comp_perm_corr) function which calculates exactly what i need, *I THINK*, but my main doubt is:
When calculating the max statistics, should i just give every nasa subdomain and every question as 2 families of variables? So that for each participants 1 t-score max is calculated between all subdomains and 1 between all questions?

Or should i input 1 pair of  (nasa subdomain score - questionnaire question score) for each participants?
Keep in mind that i'm interested in correlations between individual subdomains and questionnaires.

I apologise if there are similar questions. I think i found something similar regarding genetics, but i didn't really understand it.

I'd be happy to provide more details, if needed.
ps. i found that matlab function, but i'm more confident with R, if you have a package to suggest.

Thanks.